# How to convert date in SQL Server 2005 (andika)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I have a table in my database with a column that I want to change from `varchar` to `datetime`.

In my database the `tgl_lahir` column contains data in format : `1969-10-30 00:00:00`

```
SELECT convert (datetime, substring(tgl_lahir, 9, 2)
               +(substring(tgl_lahir, 6, 2) )
               + (left(tgl_lahir, 4)))
from penduduk
```

Can anyone help me ?

I got the following error message:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are specifying Month-Day-Year.  SQL might be expecting day month year. You also need dashes,  Like this:

```
 (datetime,(substring(tgl_lahir,6,2))+'-'+substring(tgl_lahir,9,2)+'-'+(left(tgl_lahir,4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select CONVERT (datetime,tgl_lahir,120) from penduduk
```